# Correct way to resolve data object from uibModal to a component AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, owl-carousel

I am trying to understand better about uibModal resolves works, I am trying to pass a value from a the main controller to a uibModal component, I have a collection of objects (list of objects) when I click on one of the items I am assigning an active key the the object selected, then on the Modal component I need a way to check for the item that has the "active": true so the index value of the object can be assign to the startPosition settings from owlCarousel. Right now every time I click on the items this opens the modal with the OwlCarousel and starts at 0 all the time. If user clicks on item with index value of 4 this value needs to reflected on the active owl carousel item, I think I have the correct set up, I can get the index value but I cant access this from the workModalComponent.

```
this.works[indx].active = true;
```

Then getting the index value of the item:

```
this.indx = indx;
```

I am invoking the modal with the following function:

```
      let modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open({
     windowClass: 'work-modal',
     size: 'lg',
     backdropClass: 'work-modal',
     component: 'workModal',
     resolve: {
          works: function() {
              return $ctrl.works; //passing the entire object collection to modal to display on a carousel
          },
          indx: function() {
              console.log('indx resolve', indx ); // need to pass this value to workModal component so this value can be assign to the carousel startPosition 
              return indx;
          }
      },
  });
  return modalInstance;
```

Then I have the workModal component where I am trying to set up a custom active element depending on what the user is selecting from the collection:

```
         export function workModalComponent() {
       'ngInject';

       let component = {
         restrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: 'app/components/work-modal/work-modal.html',
         bindings: {
             resolve: '<',
             close: '&'
         },
         controller: workModalController,
         controllerAs: '$ctrl',
         bindToController: true
       };

       return component;
     }

     class workModalController {

       constructor (workFeed) {
         'ngInject';

           //this.indx = indx; HOW DO I GET THIS VALUE HERE ?

           this.works = workFeed.getWorks(); // DATA DIRECTIVE

           let active = '4'; //NEED THIS VALUE TO BE ASSIGN DINAMICALLY DEPENDING ON THE VALUE ASSIGNED FROM this.indx = indx;

           this.properties = {
             items: 1,
             autoplay: true,
             autoplayTimeout: 3000,
             loop: true,
             navSpeed: 500,
             dotsSpeed: 500,
             startPosition: active, // THIS VALUE NEEDS TO UPDATED
             responsive: {
                 0: {
                     dots: true,
                     nav: true
                 },
                 576: {
                     nav: true,
                     items: 1
                 },
                 768: {
                     nav: false,

                     dots: true,
                     items: 1
                 }
             },
             onChange: function () {
             }
         };

       }

     } //workModalController
```

[image: On click getting the correct index value]

[image: Main and component logs after clicking on any items]

Comment: Don't just blog about what you did. **Describe the problem.** Tell us what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: @georgeawg Thank you for your inputs! really appreciated. I will add some updates.